# PDOException: Invalid parameter number with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Columns/Parameters are 1-based'

Tags: php, mysql

This project is really tough. I'm trying to access a database with various fields, each has a unique variable; but I'm still getting "Columns are 1-based'

Stack Trace

```
Notice: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based' in C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper.php(80): PDOStatement->bindParam(0, '447950491677', 2)
#1 C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_download_message_data\class.CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel.php(357): CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper->safe_query('SELECT id FROM ...', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_download_message_data\class.CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel.php(181): CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel->do_check_if_data_exists()
#3 C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkContainer.php(142): CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel->do_store_downloaded_message_data()
#4 C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_download_message_data\class.CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataController.php(15): CourseWorkContaine in C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper.php on line 102


$this->c_obj_stmt = $this->c_obj_database_handle->prepare($m_query_string);

// bind the parameters
if (sizeof($m_arr_query_parameters) > 0)
{
    foreach ($m_arr_query_parameters as $m_param_keys)
    {
        var_dump($m_param_keys);

        foreach ($m_param_keys as $m_param_key => $m_param_value)
        {
            $this->c_obj_stmt->bindParam($m_param_key, $m_param_value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }
}

// execute the query
$m_execute_result = $this->c_obj_stmt->execute();
$this->c_arr_database_connection_messages['execute-OK'] = $m_execute_result;
$m_database_query_execute_error = false;
```

where "$m_query_string" is:

```
SELECT id
FROM cw_messages
WHERE source = :source_terminal
    AND destination = :destination_terminal
    AND date = :message_date
    AND time = :message_time
    AND type = :message_type
    AND reference = :message_reference
    AND data = :message_data
LIMIT 1
```

Here are "$m_arr_query_parameters":

```
Array ( [:source_terminal] => Array ( [0] => 447950491677 [1] => 447950491677 ) [:destination_terminal] => Array ( [0] => 447817814149 [1] => 447817814149 ) [:message_date] => Array ( [0] => 14/08/2014 [1] => 14/08/2014 [2] => 2014-08-14 [3] => 2014-08-14 ) [:message_time] => Array ( [0] => 18:57:31 [1] => 19:48:28 ) [:message_type] => Array ( [0] => SMS [1] => SMS ) [:message_reference] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [:message_data] => Array ( [0] => Test 3 [1] => Test at 20:48 ) )
```

Here's the var dump of $m_param_keys:

> array (size=2)
>     0 => string '447950491677' (length=12)
>     1 => string '447950491677' (length=12)

Comment: can you do a var_dump of $m_param_keys just before you use it into your loop please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc B's answer was close, but in the end, the fix was actually more simple than I'd thought.

I was passing the `$m_param_key` through one too many foreach loops and needed to keep it on the outside loop.

Here's the resolved code:

```
// bind the parameters
if (sizeof($m_arr_query_parameters) > 0)
{   
  foreach ($m_arr_query_parameters as $m_param_key => $m_param_values)
    {
      foreach($m_param_values as $m_param_value)
        {
          $this->c_obj_stmt->bindParam($m_param_key, $m_param_value);
        }
    }
}

// execute the query
$m_execute_result = $this->c_obj_stmt->execute();
$this->c_arr_database_connection_messages['execute-OK'] = $m_execute_result;
$m_database_query_execute_error = false;
```

Comment: +1 for self-answered. Strangely enough, I was looking at the extra `foreach` loop and was nagging away at me, but just couldn't put my finger on it. Glad to see it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your $m_param_keys dump, you are binding 2 parameters while i guess you try to bind 7 of them according to the prameter array you posted.

Also looking at the error : Notice: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

I can pretty much tell that if you bind all the parameters you are supposed to (all the ones in your array) you won't have an error anymore.

Edit, adding the code to it :

```
$params = array(  ':source_terminal' => $m_message_source,
            ':destination_terminal' => $m_message_destination,
            ':message_date' => $m_message_date,
            ':message_time' => $m_message_time,
            ':message_type' => $m_message_type,
            ':message_reference' => $m_message_reference,
            ':message_data' => $m_message_data);

foreach( $params as $key => $val )
    $this->c_obj_stmt->bindParam($key, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped, but didn't fix the problem. I fixed it with another method.

Answer (score 1):

Your dump shows $m_param_keys to be a numerically keyed array. You're essentially trying to do

```
->bindParam(0, 447950491677)
```

PDO parameters are numbered from 1, not from 0. And you're also using **NAMED** parameters, so binding by numeric offset is also not permitted. The bind call should be

```
->bindParam(':source_terminal', $m_message_source)
```

Comment: Doesn't this then mean that I have to have 7 seperate bind_param calls? It would work, but it's not quite what I had in mind

Comment: no, you can bind in a loop, but you DO need to pass in the correct arguments.

Comment: Thanks. This helped, but didn't fix the problem. I fixed it with another method, Which I'll post in a moment.